# VBA Calculation for filtered values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with sales data, I've managed to create Autofilter based on department and copied the results into the new sheet (Output). What I'm trying to achieve is that code will multiply the results of respective month by value in "Adjustment" row.

[image: Data sheet with adjustments]

So the result is following

[image: Output sheet]

Is there a way how to process calculations within my code or I shall multiply each column in different Sub afterwards?

```
    Dim Last_Row As Long
    Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
    Dim WKS2 As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range
    Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    Set WKS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
    iMultiplier = WKS2.Range("Z18")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Last_Row = DuplicateRecords.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    DbExtract.Range("C3:R1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    DuplicateRecords.Range("A" & Last_Row).PasteSpecial
    
    DuplicateRecords.Range("$A$1:$P$400").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=WKS2.Range("V2")
   Set rn = DuplicateRecords.Range("G2:G500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
        For Each cell In rn
        iNewnumber = cell * iMultiplier
        Next cell

    
    


    End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but `Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet` declares `DbExtract` as a *variant* rather than a worksheet. "As Worksheet" only applies to the variable immediately before it.

Comment: Where exactly is that "Adjustment" row located?

Comment: @TimWilliams, on a different sheet (dashboard) where I filter based on Departments in order to check their sum which I’d like to adjust on person’s level

Comment: You can loop over the values in that Adjustments range (from Jan - Dec) and multiply the pasted values accordingly - since you know the starting row and end row for each of the pasted columns.  I don't think you can do it directly as part of the copy/paste operation: you'd have to do it after.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I see, problem is that I'm adjusting multiple departments at once so looping over the values overrides the previous ones. I've been thinking to multiply the values beforehand and then paste them.

Comment: I've updated the code but somehow my loop doesn't multiply the filtered values

Comment: What is the range address for the adjustment values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim lastRow As Long, wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim wsDash As Worksheet, rngVis As Range, numVisRows As Long
    Dim rn As Range, rngAdj As Range, m As Long, adj, c As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Data")   'consistent naming helps...
    Set wsOutput = wb.Sheets("Output")
    Set wsDash = wb.Sheets("Dashboard")
    
    'iMultiplier = wsDash.Range("Z18") '?
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set rngVis = wsData.Range("C3:R1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    numVisRows = rngVis.Cells.Count / rngVis.Columns.Count
    rngVis.Copy
    
    lastRow = wsOutput.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'start of pasted data
    wsOutput.Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial
    
    Set rngAdj = wsDash.Range("C5:N5") 'for example
    For m = 1 To rngAdj.Columns.Count 'loop the cells in the adjustments range
        adj = rngAdj.Cells(m).Value   'adjustment value
        If Len(adj) > 0 And IsNumeric(adj) Then 'have an adjustment to make?
            'loop the relevant cells in the pasted data
            For Each c In wsOutput.Cells(lastRow, "A").Offset(0, 2 + m).Resize(numVisRows).Cells
                If Len(c.Value) > 0 And IsNumeric(c.Value) Then 'any thing to adjust?
                    c.Value = c.Value * adj
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next m
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, works flawlessly. It's super fast. Could you please advice how did you manage to optimize code to this level?

Comment: It's not super-optimized, but unless you have tons of data most things are still fast.

Comment: if in rngVis(C3:R1500) in column C is a formula, is there any convenient way in VBA how to copy values instead of formula instead? Or it's easier to "paste values" manually beforehand? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you don't need the formula in the source data then yes you could perform a copy/paste values beforehand.